# Heroku Does not Load Subdomain in React App

Tags: reactjs, heroku, subdomain

I have a heroku react app hosted on `"https://www.random-slug-randomid.herokuapp.com"`

Everything works fine. Now I'm trying to add a subdomain of the format:

`"https://www.partners.<partner_id>.random-slug-randomid.herokuapp.com"`

This works fine on localhost - I can access the site by going to `"http://partners.6.localhost:3000/"` for example.

In my React `App.js` I added the following code:

```
if (window.location.host.split('.')[0] == 'partners') {
  const partnerId = window.location.host.split('.')[1];
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Component partnerId={partnerId} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

However, when I try to access the deployed app on `"https://www.partners.6.random-slug-randomid.herokuapp.com"` I get the following error:

This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in partners.6.random-slug-randomid.herokuapp.com.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

What am I missing?